# Mail.app doesn't see mail changes; requires mailbox "rebuild"

Tags: macos, email, imap, apple-mail, mailbox

I use Mail.app on 4 different computers to access the same mailboxes. I see the same problem on all of them --- if the Mail.app is running, then it catches all of the mail updates. But if a machine is turned off, when it turns back on the mailbox doesn't synchronize properly. I might delete 20 mail messages on one system and they are still on system #2 until I "rebuild."

I have seen this happen with the Mobile Me IMAP server, with Gmail, with courier IMAP, and with dovecot.

Does anybody else see this?

What should I do?

Is there a mail server that this happens less with?

It's very frustrating, as I get 200-300 mail messages a day and frequently end up handling email messages multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I use 10.6.6 on several computers (and a few mobile devices including iPhone3GS/4 and an iPad) accessing the same imap accounts (Google, MobileMe and corporate). It has not happened to me yet on Google and MobileMe. Today, for the first time I seemed to "lose" 10000's of emails on two computers simultaneously. I am following Apple's suggestion to rebuild (http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1907) which is going to take most of a day to do.

On the second computer, I simply shut Mail down. I may just try rebuilding the mailbox instead of doing everything that the ticket said to do.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas. Mail.app's imap implementation needs work, but Apple doesn't seem to care that much.